# Wrapping and appending an array-element by using jQuery.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

I'm destroying myself over this. Not the must experienced ind js. But this should be simple right?

I want to wrap each element in my 'arr'-array in `<div class="mongol"></div>` and append it to the `div#testBox`. Im using `jQuery.each` to do so, but I am not getting anything:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

  jQuery.each(arr, function() {
    $(this).append("#testBox").wrap("<div class='mongol'></div>");
  });
</script>
```

If i `alert(this)` in my jQuery.each-function then it alerts every element just fine. I don't get it.

What i am trying to achieve:

```html
<div id="testBox>
     <div class=" mongol ">one</div>
     <div class="mongol ">two</div>
     <div class="mongol ">three</div>
     <div class="mongol ">four</div>
     <div class="mongol ">five</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ]
    jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    $("#testBox").append("<div class='mongol'>" + value + '</div>');
 });
```

That works if you have a <div> like that in your Site

```
<div id="testBox"></div>
```

Comment: Cool! Sorry about the console.log() :)

Comment: haha thats just fine. Didn't even knew i existed, so now i have another debugging-tool. 2 x thanks :)

Comment: Oh for debugging javascript always use console.log() and [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) otherwise you can't loop throw stuff and so on...

Answer (score 7):

Are you confusing [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) with [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)? The code you posted will append the `testBox` element to each of your array items, which is probably not what you want (and won't work anyway). Try:

```
jQuery.each(arr, function(index, item) {
    jQuery("<div class='mongol'></div>").text(item).appendTo("#testBox");
});
```

Comment: This triggers an error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'appendTo' (?)

But what about this?
$(this).wrap("<div class='mongol'></div>").appendTo("#testBox");

Comment: @Jonas, strange, that should work. `text()` returns the jQuery object, so it should be possible to call `appendTo()` on the result. I'll investigate that. Also, I don't think your suggestion will work: `$(this)` will try to match elements whose tag name are the same as your array items (i.e. none).

Comment: Thats weird. I don't know if its the jquery.each-thing that does it. But my question has been answered now. Thanks alot for you help. Jonas :)

Comment: @Jonas, got it, `this` was remapped after the call to `jQuery()`. Using explicit parameters fixes it. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Yeah that did the trick :) Double solutions to a simple problem is twice as nice. Thank you